# Optional class initializer parameter in class initializer in Swift

Tags: swift, class, struct, init

I have a class init that is named User, and the class User contains some parameters. Now in the Offer class, you can see that I pass the User class as a param, but I want to have it as optional instead. Is there a way to have an optional class in your params? Thank you

```
struct User {
    let uid: String
    let username: String

    init(uid: String, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.username = dictionary["username"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

```
struct Offer {
    let user: User
    let caption: String
    let imageURL: String
    let creationDate: Date

    init(user: User, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.user = user
        self.caption = dictionary["caption"] as? String ?? ""
        self.imageURL = dictionary["image_url"] as? String ?? ""

        let secondsFrom1970 = dictionary["creation_date"] as? Double ?? 0
        self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFrom1970)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , make both the property user and the corresponding parameter  optional

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not `class` this is `struct` and they both are different.

you can easily create optional argument like below.
You also need to mark `user` property as optional as well.

```
struct Offer {
    let user: User?
    let caption: String
    let imageURL: String
    let creationDate: Date

    init(user: User? = nil, dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.user = user
        self.caption = dictionary["caption"] as? String ?? ""
        self.imageURL = dictionary["image_url"] as? String ?? ""

        let secondsFrom1970 = dictionary["creation_date"] as? Double ?? 0
        self.creationDate = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFrom1970)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it still there is a problem when I tried so before. I get this error which says (Missing argument for parameter 'user' in call). I am trying to tall it like this Offer(dictionary: [String: Any]). Without the user param!

Comment: @MutaebAlqahtani Just see the edit you can use default argument init here

Comment: @MutaebAlqahtani Why you have removed correct mark from my answer ?, if you still face any problem you can let me know

Comment: I did not remove anything. please vote for my question

Answer (score 1):

You code is muddling two distinct things: initialization of an object with a set of values for its members, and extracting those members from a dictionary. Just write two seperate initializers:

```
import Foundation

struct User {
    let uid: String
    let username: String

    /*
    // Due to the absence of an explicit initializer declaration,
    // the compiler will synthesize an implicit member-wise initailizer like this:
    init(uid: String, username: String) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.username = username
    }
    */
}

extension User {
    // Putting this initializer in an extension preserves he member-wise intializer
    init?(fromDict dict: [String: Any]) {
        guard let uid = dict["uid"] as? String,
              let username = dict["username"]  as? String
        else { return nil }

        self.init(uid: uid, username: username)
    }
}

struct Offer {
    let user: User
    let caption: String
    let imageURL: String
    let creationDate: Date

    /*
    // Due to the absence of an explicit initializer declaration,
    // the compiler will synthesize an implicit member-wise initailizer like this:
    init(
        user: User,
        caption: String,
        imageURL: String,
        creationDate: Date
    ) {
        self.user = user
        self.caption = caption
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.creationDate = creationDate
    }
    */
}

extension Offer {
    // Putting this initializer in an extension preserves he member-wise intializer
    init?(fromDict dict: [String: Any]) {
        guard let user = dict["user"] as? User,
              let caption = dict["caption"] as? String,
              let imageURL = dict["image_url"] as? String,
              let secondsFrom1970 = dict["creation_date"] as? Double
        else { return nil }

        self.init(
            user: user,
            caption: caption,
            imageURL: imageURL,
            creationDate: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secondsFrom1970)
        )
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. Using the nil-coalescing operator (`??`) to provide non-sensical default values in the case of `nil` is really bad practice. It hides failures and silently introduces data integrity issues; don't do it.
2. `String` is not an appropriate type for a member called `imageURL`. Use `URL`.
3. If these dicts are coming from JSON, use the `Codable` protocol to automate all of this boilerplate code.
4. `String` is a poor type for an `ID`, primarily because it's really slow, in comparison to more suitable types like `UUID` and `Int`. This is particularly true in most databases, where textual comparison is ***much*** slower than Int/UUID comparison.

Comment: Thank you, and you really know what you are doing! I really appreciate it.

Comment: One problem I found. In the User Struct, I have to have a uid param and for the Offer Struct I have to have the User param

Comment: @MutaebAlqahtani Why do you "have" to have those params? What does the calling code look like?